# is there any alternative for Bootstrap-slider-rails gem in Rails 6.0.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

As **Bootstrap-slider-rails** gem is not support for Rails 6.+ version as per document.

**railties < 6.0, >= 3.2**

So when i want to migrate from rails 5.2.4.4 to rails 6.0.3.4 am not able to get run application becuase this particular gem is not suitable.

Is there any alternative for this gem or any changes needs to done with existing gem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The repo for the gem doesn't exist but there is an option of using https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider or in my opinion, the best option would be to use bootstraps inbuild range https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/range/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="customRange1" class="form-label">Example range</label>
<input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1">
```